# cordova-plugin-media ios path for mp3 file

Tags: cordova-plugins

I have an mp3 file under `sounds` directory.

```
|- index.html
|- sounds
 |- test.mp3
```

The file plays normally in android after preceding the path with `/android_asset/www/`. However in IOS `sounds/test.mp3` doesn't play.

Do I need to modify the path in IOS too as similar to android?

Answer (score 0):

It seems cordova-media now expects a URL in the form of 
`cdvfile://path/to/file.mp3`

You can use the function toInternalURL() to get the path eg:

```
$window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(src, function(dir){

basePath = dir.toInternalURL();
media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(basePath);

});
```